# PHP to .htaccess protected html

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, ldap

I need to find a way to use PHP to enable access to .html files protected by .htaccess. The current  setup relies on mod_auth_ldap, allowing users to see the .html files.

The setup I would like to create would have a php script that the user logs into and then allows them to access the .html files while preserving the current level of security and leveraging on the existing structure.

So in short:  I need to pass along authentication from PHP to Apache2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much work, thanks to cainmi's suggestion I have come up with a solution.
My .htaccess for the protected directory looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php-wrapper/auth
RewriteRule ^(.*) /php-wrapper/wrapper.php?topage=https://%{SERVER_NAME}/php-wrapper/auth/$1
```

This passes the requests back to my php script which checks for Auth and if it passes does the following

```
$type = (get_object_vars(apache_lookup_uri("$abs_path")));
header('Content-type: '.$type['content_type']);
readfile($abs_path);
```

Responding with the file and the proper MIME type

Because some of the content I was serving had XML I had to disable short open tags. I achieved this by adding this line to the .htaccess of the directory that held the wrapper.

```
php_value short_open_tag 0
```

Stackoverflow was integral to finding this solution and for that I thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You could get PHP to handle the [auth](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) and then the login details would keep being sent by the browser headers and work for .htaccess with mod_auth_basic. This means your users have to login via the ugly browser login window thing, rather than a nice HTML/CSS one though.

Comment: I should have explained this earlier but I am using a hashed shared keys to pass authentication from another website... Unfortunately the politics around the websites prevents me from hosting them on one domain.

Comment: Not 100% sure how this works, but have a look at [this](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/tricks-for-controlling-htaccess-basic-authentication-with-php-and-mod_rewrite.html#m0-askapache0).

Comment: That looks good. Not sure how I would wrap the php... maybe include the html? but that looks like it could definitely work.

Comment: The other option is to use .htacces to redirect all requests for .html files in a certain dir to your magic auth php file, and if the user is authenticated, include the actual html file (using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), and if they aren't authenticated just show an error. This way you don't need mod_auth_basic in the .htaccess at all.

Comment: After investigating the possible solutions I ended up using your suggestion. I will edit my question with my solution as soon as I work out all the bugs.